# Rename Macbook in Apple ID screen

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id

How can I rename Macbook Pro in the screen below (taken from appleid website).

I know that on iOS I can do that by going to Settings -> General -> About -> Name but not sure how I can do the same on Mac (I am on El Capitan)

[image]

I believe it is doable as I saw something like that done on Apple's website
(as you can see all devices have John's part in them and I am trying to do the same). [Source](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/appleid/appleid-manage-hero.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Computer Name from System Prefs > Sharing > File sharing.
You can search prefs to find it...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already done so but the change didn't reflect Apple ID website (the name for the MacBook remained the same).

Comment: Mine all show that name on iCloud. Maybe it needs a reboot, re-sync, or just time to permeate across? It's not something I've really tested to see how long it takes or what further action is required, tbh, but the name currently showing on iCloud for this machine isn't the one it had a year ago; so it does update eventually - I just never tested when.